# I see “You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.” after resigning apk

Tags: android, xml, apk, jarsigner

I have an apk.  I need to change some sprites in the apk and the logo.

1. I first decompile the apk you send using: `apktool.bat d -s -f "SRacer.apk"`
2. Then I change the logos and the car sprite.
3. Then I rebuild apk using apktool.bat and parameter b.
4. Then I sign this apk using jarsigner and my keystore file
5. Then I use: `zipalign.exe -v 4 SRacer.apk`

I check the signing using jarsigner and it says its correct.

But then the admob ads don't work.

I checked the androidmanifest of the compiled apk and it has the configchanges and adactivity in the XML.

I don't know what is going wrong because instead of ads I see
"You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges" but that activity is declared, I'm sure.

Here is the manifest (AFTER its compiled and signed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.2" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.androidapps.sracer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.androidapps.sracer.MainMenuActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.androidapps.sracer.LevelSelectActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.androidapps.sracer.RecordsMenuActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.androidapps.sracer.HelpMenuActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.androidapps.sracer.PreloaderActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.androidapps.sracer.GamePlayActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using admob via the google play service library?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is, that You haven´t declared the complete attributes to the configChanges. Also, you need to set Your SDK Version maybe to a higher level, because older versions don´t support all attributes (if I am remeber correctly, it is API 13 needed). Your configChanges should look like this:

```
       <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"   
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

The attributes are case sensitive, so be sure to set them correctly.

Comment: but the target sdk is set as 15

Comment: ok, then it should be no problem to add all attributes, try it